# AspxGridView: How to Use Image As Editbutton?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have an Aspxgridview control and I enabled editing. So there is a column as "Edit". When I press it, it popups the row edit window --you all know that so far.

There are 2 columns has to be edited when I press the edit button. And I want to show a red image instead of edit button when this columns are not edited yet(I have an edited bool value in my database -0 default), after editing, I want this image to be changed with a green one. So I have the boolean column, I have 2 images and a command column with an editbutton. Possible to make that happen?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to implement.  First, you should set the CommandColumn.ButtonType to the Image value.  To customize the button's image, use the ASPxGridView's [CommandButtonInitialize](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_CommandButtonInitializetopic) event.  Here is a sample code:

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_CommandButtonInitialize(object sender, ASPxGridViewCommandButtonEventArgs e) {
    if(e.ButtonType == ColumnCommandButtonType.Edit) { 
        if(e.VisibleIndex % 2 == 0)
            e.Image.Url = "Images/Copy.bmp";
        else
            e.Image.Url = "Images/Design.bmp";
    }
}
```

Comment: At least I can see the red now. But it doesn't accept "e.ButtonType". What's missing?

Comment: which version of the ASPxGridView are you using?  Also, please paste your code here ...

Comment: DX.9.1. And there is no code yet, I just gave the event you said and it didn't show up ButtonType for e.

Comment: That way it happened: 
if (e.Button.ButtonType == ColumnCommandButtonType.Edit)
            {
            e.Button.Image.Url = "~/images/positive.png";
            }
But now the grid properties doesn't work, I mean when I click, nothing, when I click on paging numbers, nothing.

Comment: Both comments posted at the same type, take a look above please.

Comment: Hmmm.  Try to set the ASPxGridView.EnableRowsCache property to false.  Does this help?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. Now it also gives a popup as "Object reference is null" error when I click a page on pager place. But it gives it only once, not if I click again.

Comment: @confeng, post your code related to databinding please.  Also, I need to know your code within the CommandButtonInitialize event handler.

Comment: Before that, I found something like this, should I try?
http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/150216-DevExpress-Grid.aspx

Comment: This is a code which is specific to standard GridView.  Your task is also possible to implement by using this approach.  You should add an <img> element to the column's DataItemTemplate container and change its src element based on your condition.  Also, you should handle the onclick event handler of this image.

Comment: When there's nothing in "if (e.Button.ButtonType == ColumnCommandButtonType.Edit)" loop, it works. But when I add "e.Button.Image.Url = "~/images/negative.png";" line, grid controls just stop working. I can't Disable Rows Cache because when I do that, the paging doesn't work. I add an image inside, try to do eval as "ButtonType="Image" EditButton-Image-Url='<%#Eval("dosyaDurum")?"~/images/negative.png":"~/images/positive.png"%>'>" but the error is "DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.GridViewCommandColumn" doesn't have a Databinding.

Comment: The code based on databinding expression won't work.  Let's drop the CommanColumn based approach and use the templates instead.  Something like this: http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/69142/236080.aspx